# Sqlite create view select value based on the value from another table

Tags: sql, sqlite, create-view

I have two tables right now, and I am trying to create a view with columns **patient_id** and **drug_name** that includes for each patient the set of drugs for which the patient can be allergic to. Including the drug from **repostedallergies** table, and also other drug which is inferred to be allergic from the **inferredallergies** table.

```
CREATE TABLE repostedallergies (
  patient_id CHAR(5),
  drug_name  CHAR(15),
  PRIMARY KEY (patient_id, drug_name)
)
CREATE TABLE inferredallergies (
  alg CHAR(15),
  canbe_alg CHAR(15),
  PRIMARY KEY (alg, canbe_alg)
)
```

I have tried serval times, but it didn't work out

```
CREATE VIEW allergies AS
SELECT DISTINCT r.patient_id, r.drug_name
FROM reportedallergies r, inferredallergies i
WHERE r.drug_name IN (SELECT canbe_alg 
                  FROM inferredallergies i);
```

Is there any other way to add the drug_name from inferredallergie table to the view.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you want to do.

Comment: I'm assuming that alg and canbe_alg contain the names of drugs?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW allergies AS
SELECT r.patient_id, r.drug_name
FROM reportedallergies r
INNER JOIN inferredallergies i ON r.drug_name = i.canbe_alg 
GROUP BY r.patient_id, r.drug_name
```

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  *Always*!

In your case, I also think you need a `UNION ALL` to combine the information from both tables:

```
CREATE VIEW allergies AS
    SELECT r.patient_id, i.canbe_alg as drug_name
    FROM reportedallergies r JOIN
         inferredallergies i 
         ON r.drug_name = i.alg
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.patient_id, r.drug_name
    FROM reportedallergies r;
```

If you need to remove duplicates, then replace the `UNION ALL` with `UNION`.

Comment: I tried your code, but it didn't work out. The canbe_alg  cannot be added to the correspond patient_id into the VIEW. And it also creates a lot of duplicates data

Comment: @ExiaSR . . . If you are getting duplicates, then perhaps the second subquery is not needed at all.  I don't  understand your first comment at all.  Is there a problem with the first subquery?